# Two while loops into one

Tags: java

I have written this code that prompts the user to enter their month of birth and year of birth. There is some error checking: their month must be an integer and also in range from 1-12. The same for year. As it stands, I have two while loops and I can't think of a way to combine them to still get the error message when something is wrong. I can think of it if it was just going to say "Bad input: reenter" but it needs to say what is wrong with the input. It starts with month and that month has to be good before it moves on to asking the year. If the year is wrong, it will then ask to reenter year -- not go all the way back to month.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd appreciate it. The class used to check if it is an integer is one I'm required to use.

```
while(!monthDone) {
           System.out.print("Enter Month of Birth: ");
           monthInput=scan.next();

           if(!(Type.isInteger(monthInput))) {
                  System.out.println("You need to enter an integer for month");
                  monthDone=false;
           } else {
                         MOB = Integer.valueOf(monthInput);

                         if (MOB<1 || MOB>12) {
                               System.out.println("Your month is out of range");
                               monthDone=false;
                         } else {
                               monthDone=true;
                         }

                         while(!yearDone) {
                                     System.out.print("Enter Year of Birth: ");
                                     yearInput=scan.next();
                                      if(!(Type.isInteger(yearInput))) {
                                             System.out.println("You need to enter an integer for year");
                                      }
                                      else {
                                             YOB = Integer.valueOf(yearInput);
                                             if (YOB<1912 || YOB>2012)  {
                                                    System.out.println("Your year is out of range");
                                                    yearDone=false;
                                                    }
                                                    else
                                                    yearDone=true;
                                             }
                                      }
                               }
                         }
         } // else closed
 } // Outer while close
```

I am just posting the while loop. When both `monthDone && yearDone == true`, I then go on to print how old they are, etc.

Comment: Why do you want to merge them? As it stands the code is at least easy to understand conceptually. Doing tricks just to reduce the code doesn't seem like a good idea in this case.

Comment: Instead of nesting the two loops, just put them after each other. First the while loop for months, after that the while loop for years.

Comment: I would ask for the month and year as one input. This would simplify most of your code. BTW: What if I am more than 100 years old?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you should really break this code up into a few different methods - the indentation is insane.

Comment: I was told that it could be done in one loop with just one flag. I was just wondering how that could be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I might lay it out without so much nesting.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int month, year;
for (; ; scanner.nextLine()) {
    System.out.println("What is your month and year of birth as [1-12] [1900-2012]");
    if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Your month is not a number");
        continue;
    }
    month = scanner.nextInt();
    if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
        System.out.println("Your month is out of range");
        continue;
    }
    if (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Your year is not a number");
        continue;
    }
    year = scanner.nextInt();
    if (year < 1900 || year > 2012) {
        System.out.println("Your year is out of range");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Something like this was exactly what I was thinking of.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply this thus:

```
while (!monthDone) {
...
}

while (!yearDone) {
...
}
```

so you don't progress to the year input until your month input is properly completed. You'll see that you can easily extend this to day-of-month etc.